# AS3 drawing - how to layer objects so a line is behind other lines?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, draw

How can I draw line behind my line?

Can someone tell me how to make it?

I need it because I'm makin' a pool so I need the to make the stick.

This is my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mousePosition);
var MouseLine:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(MouseLine);

function mousePosition(event:MouseEvent)
{
MouseLine.graphics.clear();
MouseLine.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000, 1);
MouseLine.graphics.moveTo(375, 250);
MouseLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, behind what line?  You're wanting to draw a second line?

Comment: You can just repeat your `lineStyle`, `moveTo`, and `lineTo`. They will be drawn the in order you call them.

Comment: yep i wanna make new line.. i know these commands but my question is how to make it behind because the other line is the stick for the white ball

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash has a pretty simple layer system.  You can use `addChild(displayObject)` which always puts the passed object on top of everything else,  or `addChildAt(displayObject,index)`, which puts the passed display object at certain position (or layer if you will).  an index of 0 would place it on the bottom, an index equal to total amount of children (less 1) would place on top of everything and be the equivalent of using addChild().

If you need to change the layer ordering after the fact (after using addChild), you can use the `setChildIndex()` method, which is essentially the same as addChildAt but for things that have already been added.

If you other line was called stick:

```
addChildAt(stick,0);
```

Would put your stick behind everything else that's in the same parent.
If you wanted it one position behind the MouseLine, you could do this:

```
addChildAt(stick,getChildIndex(MouseLine));
```

---

If you're sticking to just drawing (using the graphics object) within a single object, then the lines/shapes you draw first will be behind any subsequent shape/lines.

Comment: thanks man.. this helped me to learn something but its not exactly what i asked for because u edited my question... i want to make a line and behind it to make another line, not to layer it behind the other stick i want to make billiard so i need a stick and a line for the ball(to see where the ball goes)

Comment: Not sure I understand. If my edit to the question didn't clarify on what you intended, please edit it (or undo the edit) to help clarify.  You should be able to use the information in this answer to do what you need to do.